# Start: applet not initialized (using example from book)

Tags: java, applet

I've been banging my head over this for hours. I'm using the exact same code that came straight out of the book, which claimed it was supposed to work. but every time I run the html file the applet gives me an error saying "Start: applet not initialized, when i know it should be initialized just fine. I've looked up every single error online with the same name and they all have their own reason being something wrong with their code, but mine is straight from the book which claims to work.. (Java: How to Program - Deitel 6th edition)

as shown in my command prompt history I type in appletviewer Assignment2.html with the appropriate html code in the file and get the same results. and I compiled it prior and have the class file in the same directory. these are the errors I get:

```
C:\Users\my name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment2\src\assignment2>appletviewe
r Assignment2.html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Assignment2 (wrong name: assignment2/Assignment2)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:625)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:793)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:722)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

and this is my applet code which is the same as the books:

```
package assignment2;
// Fig. 20.10: AdditionApplet.java
// Adding two floating-point numbers.
import java.awt.Graphics;       // program uses class Graphics
import javax.swing.JApplet;     // program uses class JApplet
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // program uses class JOptionPane


public class Assignment2 extends JApplet 
{
   private double sum; // sum of values entered by user

   // initialize applet by obtaining values from user
   public void init()
   {
      String firstNumber;  // first string entered by user
      String secondNumber; // second string entered by user

      double number1; // first number to add
      double number2; // second number to add

      // obtain first number from user
      firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
         "Enter first floating-point value" );

      // obtain second number from user
      secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
         "Enter second floating-point value" );

      // convert numbers from type String to type double
      number1 = Double.parseDouble( firstNumber ); 
      number2 = Double.parseDouble( secondNumber );

      sum = number1 + number2; // add numbers
   } // end method init

   // draw results in a rectangle on applet�s background
   public void paint( Graphics g )
   {
      super.paint( g ); // call superclass version of method paint

      // draw rectangle starting from (15, 10) that is 270 
      // pixels wide and 20 pixels tall
      g.drawRect( 15, 10, 270, 20 );

      // draw results as a String at (25, 25)
      g.drawString( "The sum is " + sum, 25, 25 );
   } // end method paint
} // end class AdditionApplet
```

and here is my html file code in case u want to be sure.

```
<html>
<applet code = "Assignment2.class" width = "300" height = "50">
</applet>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<html>
<applet code = "assignment2.Assignment2.class" width = "300" height = "50">
</applet>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont think thats it.. i ran another html file with the .class extension in it and it worked

Comment: yup i tried removing it, saved it, recompiled, and ran, didnt work. :(

Comment: You're right, good call. Try: <applet code = "assignment2 .Assignment2.class" width = "300" height = "50">

Comment: `Wrong name` specifies there might be mistake with class name with package specified. I made the edit on my answer.

Comment: nope, saved html file, recompiled, ran, same thing >__<

Comment: Is your html file in the src\assignment2 directory? The location of your html is probably the issue. It is working fine for me.

Comment: so is your directory is as follows: `src/assignment2/Assignment2` and `src/yourhtmlfile.html`?

Comment: Your html file should be outside assignment2, and call it with `assignment2.Assignment2.class` mentioned above.

Comment: interesting.. it was in Assignment2\src\assignment2, but not Assignment2\src .. and that got it to work.. directories are a pain in the ass... thanks...

Comment: now i have two horus to turn in the rest of the assignment @_@ u saved me tho

Comment: No problem! Good luck! Don't hesitate to post a new question if you run into additional issues.

Comment: thanks i finished it in less than an hour xD with about 40 minutes to spare

Comment: Awesome! That's great news.